# Looking for a good flight cost comparison site for flexible schedule

Tags: air-travel, budget, flight-search-engines

I'm looking for a good flight cost comparison site for flexible schedule.

Let's say I want to plan a one week trip in October. I really do not mind when. 
Means I need a site where I can set the destination and have some kind of a table with the cheapest prices on each day.
Can be different carriers for each leg.

Most of the sites give you up to +-7 days

Are there any sites which give you -+30 days?

i am not asking about flexible destination but about flexible schedule. non of the sites like: itasoftware, skyscanner, or kayak gives you the flexibility im looking for. 
i.e. kayak gives you +- 3 days –

Comment: she is asking mainly about flexible destination not about  flexible schedule.
non of the mentioned sites there itasoftware, skyscanner, kayak gives you the flexibility im looking for. i.e. kayak gives you +- 3 days

Comment: Skyscanner does "whole month" view - why isn't that good enough?

Comment: ok, now i see it. never noticed before that Skyscanner has a "whole month" view. thanks

Comment: ITA Matrix also has a "calendar view" that looks over 28 days